# Optimal Placement of Boxes of Apples in a Warehouse

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I came across a problem at work yesterday which looked like it might have some interesting mathematical aspects to it.

Suppose you're the manager of a cold store - a refrigerator the size of a warehouse - for boxes of apples. Also, suppose the following:

- Apples come in two sizes: large and small.
- Boxes of apples thus come in two sizes too: mostly large and mostly small.
- The ratio of mostly large to mostly small boxes is close to 1:1.
- Boxes of apples are cube-shaped.
- The cold store is laid out like a chess board, an 8 by 8 grid, with each box taking up one square. (Assume that boxes cannot be stacked on top of each other.)
- All apples are harvested - and thus put into the cold store - in October.
- At the end of October, almost all of the warehouse's 64 squares are occupied, i.e. **there is no way to retrieve the boxes at the back without first creating a path to it** by removing other boxes.
- There is exactly one entrance/exit point, one box wide, half way down one of the sides.

Now suppose that, for the other 11 months, November to September, a coin is tossed. On the basis of that toss, supermarkets will either want to purchase, for that month, 90% small apples and 10% large apples, or vice versa.

Given the above, **what is the most efficient way to put boxes into the store in October** in terms of minimising the work that the cold store's fork-lift truck drivers will have to carry out?

### Bonus Questions

- Suppose I changed the ratio of mostly large to mostly small boxes and/or the ratio of small to large apples which supermarkets wanted to buy. Would that change the problem drastically?
- Suppose you were allowed to stack boxes on top of each other to, say, 8 boxes high, but the store would still be filled to close to 100% capacity. Would that change the problem drastically?

Comment: What's the access to the store like? A door one box wide in the middle of one side?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I should have specified. There is only one entrance/exit. And, for the sake of argument, let's say that it's one box wide. (If it makes for a more interesting answer, please feel free to adjust this, or indeed any other conditions set out in the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very interesting, I'm afraid. Put all of one type on the left, and all of the other type on the right. Then removing a box of one type will expose another box of the same type, so it shouldn't be necessary to do any shuffling around of boxes.

Comment: Thank you. 'Not very interesting' is actually a really useful answer - much as I would like to have uncovered someting more enthralling. I wonder: what if, instead of "small" and "large", we had five size categories, A to E, with apples being distributed across the categories according to a (rough) normal distribution. Would that make things more interesting? And what if supermarkets' demands were out of proportion to the sizes harvested? ("No" is still a useful answer!)

Comment: Doesn't make much difference. The most interesting case would be where there are many more categories than there are boxes accessible in a full storeroom, but even there I you'd want to group them together at the back and it's only the pinch point that's really interesting.